# SQL adding additional sub query to exclude results of main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm running reports on a SQL 2008 database with 2 tables. Parent Table is Account, Child table is Contracts and they are Linked on a unique identifier field - AccountID.

My goal is to pull all Accounts and Contracts based off of what type of contracts are present.

I have this query right now:

```
Select Account.*, C.* from Account

Left Join Contracts C
on C.AccountID=Account.AccountId

Where 

(Case when C.T1 = 'TYPE1' or C.T1 = 'TYPE2' or C.T1 = 'TYPE3' or C.T1 = 'TYPE4' or C.T1 = 'TYPE5' or C.T1 = 'TYPE6' Then 0 Else 1 END) = 0 
and EXISTS (Select E.AccountID, E.T1 from Contracts E Where E.AccountID = C.AccountID and (E.T1 LIKE 'TYPE6' and Convert(Date,E.End_Date) = Convert(Date,C.End_Date)))

Order by Account.AccountID
```

The idea is to pull all accounts that have Contract where T1 = TYPE1-6, but only if they have a contract Where T1 = TYPE6. This gives results like this:

```
AccountID   Contract    T1
   1             1       4
   1             2       5
   1             3       6

   2             4       6
   2             5       2
   2             6       6

   3             7       6
   3             8       6
   3             9       6
```

The next thing I need from this is for it to **exclude accounts that ONLY have Contract TYPE6** and I am completely lost. The ideal result is that I would get all 3 contracts for accounts 1 & 2, But would drop Account 3 from the results.

My assumption is that I will need an additional query that gives me the results that I do not want.I don't fully understand EXCEPT statements but I feel like one might need to be put in here?

This query gives me all the Accounts/Contracts that should not be included in the results of my first:

```
Select Account.*, C.* from Account 

Left Join Contracts C
on C.AccountID=Account.AccountId

where
(Case When C.T1 = 'TYPE6' Then 0 Else 1 End) = 0
and NOT EXISTS (Select E.AccountID, E.T1 from Contracts E Where E.AccountID = C.AccountID and E.T1 NOT LIKE '%TYPE6%'and Convert(Date,E.End_Date) = Convert(Date,C.End_Date)) 


Order by Account.AccountID
```

Is there a way for me to say 'Give me everything from  the first Query but exclude everything from the 2nd?'

Also any advice on cleaning up my statements would be appreciated. I'm not claiming to be good at this.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need some details in order to help much. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I don't understand why account 2 is in your results. It doesn't comply with your criteria "but only if they have a contract Where T1 = TYPE6". Account 2 only has types 1, 2, and 3. No type 6.

Comment: @SeanLange This is all the information I can give. I can't give you any sample data.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sorry about that I just typed out the table too quickly and didn't check it properly.

Comment: You have some sample data in your post. How about some table structure? Nobody is asking for trade secrets or anything, we are asking for details relevant to your question so we can help. Post up your structure and mock up some dummy data. And what the desired output would be on your dummy data.

Comment: @SeanLange I guess I just don't understand how I haven't already don't that where I provided 3 'accounts' with 'contracts' and 'types.' You can ignore the end_date, I shouldn't have included that there to begin with because it just adds extra complications, that was my fault.

Comment: Because from what you posted we have to guess at datatypes. And your query you posted doesn't match the sample data you provided. You have "C.T1 = 'TYPE1'" in your query but in your sample data T1 are all numbers. And even if this discrepancy didn't exist you are forcing the people who are volunteering their time to spend a lot of time setting up the problem. I don't want to create these tables on my end so I can then create insert statements all before I can work on your issue. If you were paying me I would be thrilled, but as free help it isn't likely going to happen from many people.

Comment: On a sidenote: If you outer join `contracts`, but then only keep records with type 1 to 6 in your `WHERE` clause, then you dismiss all outer joined records. You can just as well write `INNER JOIN` so as to be more clear and not giving the DBMS unnecessary work. Moreover, we never use `CASE WHEN` in a `WHERE` clause. `CASE WHEN` is made to create a boolean expression where we need it (in `SELECT` or `ORDER BY`). The `WHERE` cause, however, is a boolean expression itself. So simply use `AND`, `OR` and `IN` there. E.g.: `WHERE C.T1 IN ('TYPE1', 'TYPE2', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

The last condition should do the trick with a test of existence of another contract that is not of type 6 (I didnt test it locally)

```
Select Account.*, C.* from Account

        Left Join Contracts C
        on C.AccountID=Account.AccountId

        Where 

        (Case when C.T1 = 'TYPE1' or C.T1 = 'TYPE2' or C.T1 = 'TYPE3' or C.T1 = 'TYPE4' or C.T1 = 'TYPE5' or C.T1 = 'TYPE6' Then 0 Else 1 END) = 0 
        and EXISTS (Select E.AccountID, E.T1 from Contracts E Where E.AccountID = C.AccountID and (E.T1 LIKE 'TYPE6' and Convert(Date,E.End_Date) = Convert(Date,C.End_Date)))
    AND (C.T1 <> 'TYPE6' OR EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Contracts con WHERE con.AccountId = Account.AccountId AND con.T1 <> 'TYPE6' ))

        Order by Account.AccountID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this won't work for Accounts that have 1 contract that is TYPE6 but it did get me closer!

Answer (score 0):

You want information on an account (whether any or all its records are of type 6). So group by account ID and check what you have.

```
select accountid
from contracts
where t1 between 1 and 6
group by accountid
having count(case when t1 = 6 then 1 end) > 0 -- at least one record of type 6
   and count(case when t1 <> 6 then 1 end) > 0 -- at least one record of type 1 to 5
```

You can then select the records for these accounts:

```
select * 
from accounts a
join contracts c on c.accountid = a.accountid
where c.t1 between 1 and 6 and c.accountid in (<above query>);
```

An alternative where you read the table only once is using the analytic function `COUNT OVER` instead of `COUNT`:

```
select accountid, contract, t1
from
(
  select 
    a.*, c.*,
    count(case when c.t1 = 6 then 1 end) over (partition by c.accountid) as c6,
    count(case when c.t1 <> 6 then 1 end) over (partition by c.accountid) as c12345
  from accounts a
  join contracts c on c.accountid = a.accountid
  where c.t1 between 1 and 6
) mydata
where c6 > 0 and c12345 > 0;
```

Comment: In your example all the columns you select exist in `contracts`. If you really want no additional data from `accounts` then remove the table from above queries.